# Can't pass value in url codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

My pagination code is below. I can't catch the value from url and also pagination is not working:

```
public function categories_product(){
    $categoryid   = $_GET['catId'];
    $categoryname = $_GET['cname'];
    $data = array();

    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "pages/categories_product?catId=".$categoryid."&cname=".$categoryname ;
}
```

Comment: isn't `$_GET` disabled on default with CI? and why not just use `->input->get()`

Comment: you overriding your `$config["base_url"] ` cause damage your application ...there are many css and js files are including based on `base_url`

Answer (score 0):

Try perhaps this instead of using query string (I think you need to enable query string in Codeigniter config file, but I'm not sure as I haven't used it a long time)

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "pages/categories_product/".$categoryid."/".$categoryname;
// Telling pagination that pagination parameters will go from 5th segment
$config['uri_segment'] = 5;

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Additionally this is more SEO friendly, and also more in Codeigniter style.

Find **Customizing pagination** here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: Have updated link to codeigniter user guide as Ellislab does not deal with it any more you can now find the old and new user guide here http://www.codeigniter/docs

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('pagination'); 
$config['per_page']= 10;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
$config['base_url'] = 'URL where you want to run pagination';
```

Count total number of records

```
$this->data['totalcount'] = 'total records';
```

initialize library

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config);



$this->data['paginglinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->data['per_page'] = $this->uri->segment(4);

        $this->data['page'] = $offset;
    $this->data['per_page_display'] = $config['per_page'];
```